# Bootstrap footer icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

This is the skeleton of most of my websites I like to create. I would like to be able to add image links instead of having to reference photos on my computer. I was hoping to get some help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>$title$</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap template</h1>
  <p>$text$</p> 
    <footer class="blog-footer">
      <p>Made by Kevin Leong</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="/assets/social-icons/facebook_icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="img-fluid"></a>
  
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="/assets/social-icons/twitter-icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="img-fluid"></a>
  
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="/assets/social-icons/instagram.png" width="30" height="30" class="img-fluid"></a>
  
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="/assets/social-icons/linked-in-icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="img-fluid"></a>
  
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="/assets/social-icons/pinterest-icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="img-fluid"></a>
  
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="/assets/social-icons/flickr-icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="img-fluid"></a>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your question about how to host image files online in a publicly accessible format?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference external images like this:

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/Aster_Tataricus.JPG/321px-Aster_Tataricus.JPG" />
```

**Right click** on any image online and select `copy image address`, then paste it in the `src=""` of an `img` element. But only use images from places like https://commons.wikimedia.org/ and https://www.pexels.com/ that give you permission to use their images.